How can I skip rows by a specific column if the column is not part of the order by statement
I'm using PostgreSQL 14.13.
Here is a fiddle for it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wtCiz8QtBSkZ3WyS8vRDkQ/0
I have this query that orders cards in a smart way for students
select setseed(-0.07687704123439676);
SELECT cards.id,
       dc.deck_id,
       cards.question,
       cards.answer,
       uc.practice_session_sr_level
FROM cards
         LEFT JOIN decks_cards dc ON cards.id = dc.card_id
         LEFT JOIN user_card uc ON cards.id = uc.card_id

WHERE dc.deck_id = 2907
GROUP BY cards.id,
         uc.practice_session_sr_level,
         dc.deck_id
ORDER BY
    --   cards.id = 98486 desc,
         practice_session_sr_level = 'NOT_LEARNED' DESC,
         practice_session_sr_level = 'AGAIN' DESC,
         practice_session_sr_level = 'HARD' DESC,
         practice_session_sr_level = 'EASY' DESC,
         practice_session_sr_level = 'GOOD' DESC,
         RANDOM()
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;

which gives me a result like this:
98512,2907,How do you say 'family'?,rodzina,NOT_LEARNED
98498,2907,How do you say 'teacher' in Polish?,nauczyciel,NOT_LEARNED
98580,2907,What is the Polish word for 'forest'?,las,NOT_LEARNED
98486,2907,How do you say 'friend' in Polish?,przyjaciel,NOT_LEARNED
98525,2907,What is the Polish word for 'heart'?,serce,NOT_LEARNED
98528,2907,How do you say 'solution' in Polish?,rozwiązanie,NOT_LEARNED
98497,2907,What is the Polish word for 'school'?,szkoła,NOT_LEARNED
98540,2907,How do you say 'drink' in Polish?,napój,NOT_LEARNED
...

I would like to enable the user to press on a card and start learning from that card onward.
For example, if the user press the card with id 98486, it should skip the cards before that one.
If I uncomment cards.id = 98486 desc, I get
Current result
98486,2907,How do you say 'friend' in Polish?,przyjaciel,NOT_LEARNED
98512,2907,How do you say 'family'?,rodzina,NOT_LEARNED
98498,2907,How do you say 'teacher' in Polish?,nauczyciel,NOT_LEARNED
98580,2907,What is the Polish word for 'forest'?,las,NOT_LEARNED
98525,2907,What is the Polish word for 'heart'?,serce,NOT_LEARNED
98528,2907,How do you say 'solution' in Polish?,rozwiązanie,NOT_LEARNED
98497,2907,What is the Polish word for 'school'?,szkoła,NOT_LEARNED
98540,2907,How do you say 'drink' in Polish?,napój,NOT_LEARNED
...

expected result
98486,2907,How do you say 'friend' in Polish?,przyjaciel,NOT_LEARNED
98525,2907,What is the Polish word for 'heart'?,serce,NOT_LEARNED
98528,2907,How do you say 'solution' in Polish?,rozwiązanie,NOT_LEARNED
98497,2907,What is the Polish word for 'school'?,szkoła,NOT_LEARNED
98540,2907,How do you say 'drink' in Polish?,napój,NOT_LEARNED
...

How can I update the query so PostgreSQL can skip the rows before the specified id?

You want to return only the cards where id > 98486? Then just add this condition to where :)

You should (or could) add a ROWNUMBER to  your results, and find out which row number is linke to 98486, and then select WHERE rownumber >= .... that row number.

I'm pretty sure that a guy who has a rep of 14k can easily do a simple WHERE id > id - perhaps you could construct a fiddle and edit your question - or does the simple WHERE... work for you?

@Vérace ahah thank you, not sure my rep tells much about my SQL skills, but yes a WHERE id > id doesn't work here, because the ids are not part of the ordering per say, the order is based on practice_session_sr_level, so I don't want to skip id by their value

@Luuk ah I can try that!

I made a fiddle for it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wtCiz8QtBSkZ3WyS8vRDkQ/0

@KevinAmiranoff I think you forgot to hit update in the fiddle - you posted the same one you have in the question.


Don't order by random() limit 10. Use the tablesample clause instead.
If practice_session_sr_level is an enum, the values in it have implied numerical values/sorting order. You can rearrange the enum type definition (or make one, if it's not an enum yet) to
 create type practice_session_sr_level_enum_type 
   as enum('NOT_LEARNED','AGAIN','HARD','EASY','GOOD');
 alter table user_card 
   alter column practice_session_sr_level
   type practice_session_sr_level_enum_type
   using(practice_session_sr_level::practice_session_sr_level_enum_type);

And that simplifies the ordering to
order by practice_session_sr_level;

Which is also way faster than evaluating the 5 expressions, however simple.
@Luuk's immediate suggestion to use row_number()over(..) is right on the money:
demo at db<>fiddle
 SELECT row_number()over w1,
        cards.id,
        dc.deck_id,
        cards.question,
        cards.answer,
        uc.practice_session_sr_level
 FROM cards
          LEFT JOIN decks_cards dc ON cards.id = dc.card_id
          LEFT JOIN user_card uc ON cards.id = uc.card_id
 WHERE dc.deck_id = 2907
 GROUP BY cards.id,
          uc.practice_session_sr_level,
          dc.deck_id
 WINDOW w1 AS(ORDER BY practice_session_sr_level,
                       RANDOM() )
 ORDER BY row_number
 LIMIT 10 OFFSET 4/*the 4 is taken from the row_number clicked*/-1;

You can also wrap the whole thing in a subquery and use a where row_number>=4.


Thank you for the detailed answer and fiddle. This points me in the right direction. The enum suggestion is very good.
However, I have a couple of questions. I could get the offset index from the front end, indeed, but then do I still needrow_number? Wouldn't offset be enough to skip the first rows?
I would have ideally computed this offset number from the cards.id position. But maybe just passing an initial offset might be the simplest solution.

@KevinAmiranoff If you offload your counting/row numbering to front end, you can ditch row_number completely. Same goes for order by, limit or even where clauses - both sides can handle these so there's no need to duplicate the work already done on either end. That's not to say I recommend moving those other parts - while numbering rows is comparably cheap on both ends, PostgreSQL planner uses the rest to optimise the execution of the query so it's best to keep them in there.

what I am trying to say is that in you example the offset 4 - 1 is hardcoded. So row_number() is unused it seems, unless there is something I don't understand.

@KevinAmiranoff I understood you're running this twice: the first time you offer all rows to the user, then they click the one they wish to start from and you need to modify the query to skip everything that comes before the selected position. As I mentioned at the end of the answer, you can wrap that whole thing in a CTE or subquery, which would allow you to refer to row_number from a where condition - the effect will be the same, just using more code. The is a performance benefit the wrapping with row_number>=4: Postgres will use it to optimise the plan.
